# Selecting an element with same class names using css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this ugly generated code and I want to pick an element and add an additional attribute. I can only use CSS to do this. I tried a few things such as `#CHART_1_control div:nth-of-type` and `nth-child` but I seem to be getting lost with all the `<g>` classes. I'm also not sure if that's the direction I should be heading.

I'm trying to get to the last `<g>` class and change the three `<rect>` to include an additional attribute. Is that possible to do?

```
                                 <g class="v-datapoint-group" fill-opacity="0.4" stroke-opacity="0.4">
                                    <g>
                                       <path d="M23.3876953125,126.6L23.3876953125,126.6L70.1630859375,126.6L70.1630859375,126.6L116.93847656249999,126.6L116.93847656249999,126.6L163.7138671875,126.6L163.7138671875,126.6L210.4892578125,126.6L210.4892578125,35.87L257.2646484375,35.87L257.2646484375,126.6" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="1" class="v-bar-series-path" display="none"></path>
                                       <g data-id="0" data-datapoint-id="1" class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint v-datapoint-default" transform="translate(23.3876953125, 126.6)" fill-opacity="0.4">
                                          <rect width="46.775390625" height="0" fill="#008000" stroke-opacity="0.4"></rect>
                                       </g>
                                       <g data-id="1" data-datapoint-id="2" class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint v-datapoint-default" transform="translate(116.93847656249999, 126.6)" fill-opacity="0.4">
                                          <rect width="46.775390625" height="0" fill="#ff9900" stroke-opacity="0.4"></rect>
                                       </g>
                                       <g data-id="2" data-datapoint-id="3" class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint v-datapoint-selected" transform="translate(210.4892578125, 35.87)" fill-opacity="1">
                                          <rect width="46.77539062500001" height="90.72999999999999" fill="#cc0000" stroke-opacity="1" contenteditable="true" stroke="#445a7c" stroke-width="1px"></rect>
                                       </g>
                                    </g>
```

So here we change the fill color just using css on the last 3 rect

Full Code below:

```
.v-datapoint rect{
fill:blue;
}
<div id="CHART_1_control" style="width:353px;height:200px" class="zenControl">
   <div class="uvb-vizframe-container">
      <div style="width: 353px; height: 200px; visibility: visible; position: relative;">
         <div class="viz-controls-chart-holder viz-controls-common-scrollable" style="position: relative; width: 353px; height: 200px;">
            <div class="viz-controls-chart-layer" style="position: absolute; width: 353px; height: 200px; visibility: visible;">
               <div id="UIComp_0" class="v-info" aria-labelledby="UIComp_0-title" tabindex="0" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative; font-size: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; user-select: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); outline: none;">
                  <svg class="v-m-root" focusable="false" tabIndex="-1" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; display: block; cursor: default;">
                     <defs></defs>
                     <g class="v-m-desc-title">
                        <title id="UIComp_0-title">An Interactive Column Chart  </title>
                     </g>
                     <g class="v-m-action-layer-group js-zen-nozoom"></g>
                     <g class="v-m-decoration-layer-group"></g>
                     <g class="v-m-background">
                        <rect class="v-background-body viz-plot-background v-morphable-background" x="0" y="0" width="353" height="200" style="fill:transparent"></rect>
                     </g>
                     <g class="v-m-title" transform="translate(48.34765625, 24)"></g>
                     <g class="v-m-legendGroup" transform="translate(329, 24)" role="listbox">
                        <g class="v-m-legend" transform="translate(0,0)">
                           <rect class="v-bound" width="0" height="0" visibility="hidden"></rect>
                        </g>
                     </g>
                     <g class="v-m-main" transform="translate(24, 24)">
                        <g class="v-m-plot" transform="translate(24.34765625, 0)">
                           <rect class="v-background-body viz-plot-background v-morphable-background" x="0" y="0" width="280.65234375" height="126.6" style="fill:transparent"></rect>
                           <line class="v-background-border viz-plot-background-border" x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="126.6" style="stroke: rgb(216, 216, 216); stroke-width: 1;"></line>
                           <line class="v-background-border viz-plot-background-border" x1="280.65234375" y1="0" x2="280.65234375" y2="126.6" style="stroke: rgb(216, 216, 216); stroke-width: 1;"></line>
                           <line class="v-background-border viz-plot-background-border" x1="0" y1="0" x2="280.65234375" y2="0" style="stroke: rgb(216, 216, 216); stroke-width: 1;"></line>
                           <line class="v-background-border viz-plot-background-border" x1="0" y1="126.6" x2="280.65234375" y2="126.6" style="stroke: rgb(216, 216, 216); stroke-width: 1;"></line>
                           <clipPath id="plot_main_clipPath_9e2f712c-3fd6-4720-80a0-0040e5b7a732">
                              <rect y="-1" width="281.65234375" height="127.6"></rect>
                           </clipPath>
                           <rect class="v-plot-bound v-bound v-zoom-plot" width="280.65234375" height="126.6" fill="transparent"></rect>
                           <g clip-path="url(#plot_main_clipPath_9e2f712c-3fd6-4720-80a0-0040e5b7a732)">
                              <g class="v-plot-main" role="list" transform="translate(0, 0)">
                                 <g class="v-gridline-group">
                                    <g class="v-gridline" stroke="#d8d8d8" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
                                       <line class="v-gridline-mainline" x1="0" y1="126.6" x2="280.65234375" y2="126.6"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g class="v-gridline" stroke="#d8d8d8" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
                                       <line class="v-gridline-mainline" x1="0" y1="84.4" x2="280.65234375" y2="84.4"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g class="v-gridline" stroke="#d8d8d8" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
                                       <line class="v-gridline-mainline" x1="0" y1="42.2" x2="280.65234375" y2="42.2"></line>
                                    </g>
                                    <g class="v-gridline" stroke="#d8d8d8" stroke-width="1" shape-rendering="crispEdges">
                                       <line class="v-gridline-mainline" x1="0" y1="0" x2="280.65234375" y2="0"></line>
                                    </g>
                                 </g>
                                 <g class="v-datapoint-group" fill-opacity="0.4" stroke-opacity="0.4">
                                    <g>
                                       <path d="M23.3876953125,126.6L23.3876953125,126.6L70.1630859375,126.6L70.1630859375,126.6L116.93847656249999,126.6L116.93847656249999,126.6L163.7138671875,126.6L163.7138671875,126.6L210.4892578125,126.6L210.4892578125,35.87L257.2646484375,35.87L257.2646484375,126.6" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke="#008000" stroke-width="1" class="v-bar-series-path" display="none"></path>
                                       <g data-id="0" data-datapoint-id="1" class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint v-datapoint-default" transform="translate(23.3876953125, 126.6)" fill-opacity="0.4">
                                          <rect width="46.775390625" height="0" fill="#008000" stroke-opacity="0.4"></rect>
                                       </g>
                                       <g data-id="1" data-datapoint-id="2" class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint v-datapoint-default" transform="translate(116.93847656249999, 126.6)" fill-opacity="0.4">
                                          <rect width="46.775390625" height="0" fill="#ff9900" stroke-opacity="0.4"></rect>
                                       </g>
                                       <g data-id="2" data-datapoint-id="3" class="v-datapoint v-morphable-datapoint v-datapoint-selected" transform="translate(210.4892578125, 35.87)" fill-opacity="1">
                                          <rect width="46.77539062500001" height="90.72999999999999" fill="#cc0000" stroke-opacity="1" contenteditable="true" stroke="#445a7c" stroke-width="1px"></rect>
                                       </g>
                                    </g>
                                 </g>
                              </g>
                           </g>
```

Comment: You say you want to add an attribute with only CSS. That's not really possible. Also `g` is an element, not a class.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit? Are you trying to target `.v-datapoint-group` or the last `<g>` tag inside of it?

Comment: There are multiple charts in the same page with all the same names. The only unique ID is at the very top of the full code above named "CHART_1_control".

I'm trying to get to the 3 < rect > at the bottom to add an additional attribute.

<g data-id="0" ...>  
<rect "additional attribute" ... </rect>
</g>

<g data-id="1" ...>
<rect "additional attribute" ... </rect>
</g>

Comment: I initially thought you're talking about CSS properties, but it turns out you're actually talking about HTML attributes. So, Iike @HereticMonkey mentioned above, it's not possible to add / change HTML attributes with CSS.

Comment: If it's not possible, how can I accomplish this in js?

Comment: @volt does that mean this line is not css?

rect width="46.775390625" height="0" fill="#008000" stroke-opacity="0.4"

Comment: ^^ Those are element properties/attributes, not CSS.

Comment: it is possible, see edited question

Comment: @DCR why did you edit the answer into the question?

Comment: Also, that's not adding an attribute to an element, that's applying a style property to an element.